# Dell PowerEdge T310 Fan Noise Reduction

Tags: bios, fan, firmware, windows-server, dell-poweredge

I'm working with a Dell PowerEdge T310 that's terribly loud. Unfortunately I'm in a situation where I need to install it into an office with people working. According to this thread it seems as though the noise level can be brought down SIGNIFICANTLY enough for such a scenario: [T310 Fan Noise](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/T310-Fan-Noise/td-p/3516945)

This forum post says to do two things:

1. Get BIOS update
2. Get the ESM firmware update

It's easy enough to get the BIOS update from [the drivers page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/poweredge-t310/drivers), however the ESM update is a little more tricky.  For example, if you get the "Embedded Server Management" iDRAC updates and try to install them, they will not even apply without the Operating System essentially being Windows Server 2008 R2 x86.  I tried to update with Windows Server 2012 R2, no luck. Backed down to 2008 R2 x86 and it still failed.

The error is a dialogue that says:
[image: This Update Package is not compatible with your system configuration]

```
Error
This Update Package is not compatible with your system configuration.
```

Same result with iDRAC Monolithic Release 2.92, A00.

***Can someone specify precisely which updates, as per this forum or your own experience, that need to be applied in order to get the fans to operate at more reasonable levels?***

Again, the BIOS is straight forward and this link seems to work: [Dell Server BIOS PowerEdge T310 Version 1.14.0](https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER05039804M/1/T310_BIOS_6KYVJ_WN32_1.14.0.EXE), however I really think I need a specific ESM update link that will install and also to know what OS version is necessary to apply it.

After all of this, which power management option is best to set it at within the BIOS to effect proper change in fan noise?

Comment: Does your server have the idrac and ESM? If your server was not purchased with these options you won't be able to use them. Also, server fans are loud. Even "quiet" mode is still likely to be quite loud compared with the noise levels of computers we are used to working around.

Comment: Yes, it does have the iDRAC ESM. I've worked around a lot of servers and this should be a bit more quiet.